# PDO Classes across multiple websites

Tags: php, web, pdo

I have written PDO classes with DB connection for a single website but what I actually need to use the same class across multiple websites.

**The idea is that when I change something in the class the changes will reflect in all my website not just one but these 2 websites will still use 2 separate DBs**

Could you please advice me on how to solve my problem or where should I start looking

e.g.

```
core\ classes \ product.class.php

Web_1 
-databass.class.php for Web_1 using the core\classes\

Web_2
-databass.class.php for Web_2 using the core\classes\
```

---

This is my part of my code

**File dbConfig.php**

```
<?php 
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('USER_NAME', 'test');
define('USER_PASSWORD', '********');
define('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'test_db');?>
```

**File databass.class.php**

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'dbConfig.php');
class DatabasePDO
{
    private static $_instance = array();
    static function getInstance ($dbName = DB_NAME)
    {
        if (! array_key_exists($dbName, self::$_instance)) {
            $dsn = DB_TYPE . ":host=" . HOSTNAME . ";dbname=" . $dbName;
            try {
                self::$_instance[$dbName] = new PDO($dsn, USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD);
                self::$_instance[$dbName]->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
                die();
            }
        }
        return self::$_instance[$dbName];
    }
}?>
```

**File product.class.php**

```
<?php
require_once "databass.class.php";

class products_CLS
{
    private $pid = null;
    private $title  = '';

    private static $dbConn = null;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        self::initializeConnection();
    }

    private static function initializeConnection ()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$dbConn)) {
            self::$dbConn = DatabasePDO::getInstance();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the $productid
     */
    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->pid;
    }   

    /**
     * @return the $producttitle
     */
    public function getProductTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}?>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: product.class.php uses require_once "databass.class.php"; which means this class is only used on this DB but what should I do if I want to use the same class on different website.I need to copy the class and put it in another fodler but I want to keep one core class which is used on multi websites

Comment: You will probably want to eliminate the singleton and use parameterized configuration instead of constants. This will allow you to create multiple connection objects with different configs using the same class.

Comment: Why can't you just use `require_once "/path/to/databass.class.php";` on the other site as well?

Comment: I am sorry cbednarski but what do you mean by saying "use parameterized configuration" can you point to some article etc..

Comment: What if I have 50 websites using the same class I can't just use require_once "/path/to/databass.class.php";

Comment: Why not? What's wrong with it? Why certainly you can't? What makes you unable to write this line of code?

Comment: So what you mean is to add "require_once "/path/to/databass_web_1.class.php"; require_once "/path/to/databass_web_2.class.php";" to each class for each websites I have. Is that what you mean ??

Comment: where did you get that `databass_web_1.class.php`? What is that?

Comment: I changed databass.class.php to databass_web_1.class.php for Website 1  and databass_web_2.class.php for Website 2 each pointing to different dbConfig

Comment: I think I know what you mean :) Each of my classes will have require_once pointing to each website db connection

Comment: What for you changed databass.class.php to databass_web_1.class.php for Website 1?

Comment: `"Each of my classes will have require_once pointing to each website db connection"` - they do it already

Comment: @Your Common Sense I don't know whether is me who don't get your point or you not understanding what I need :( I will have 2 Websites e.g. Web_1 pointing to DB_Web_1 and Web_2 pinting to DB_Web_2 in this case I need 2 databass.class.php pointing to different databases but still using the same class product.class.php

Comment: it is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'dbConfig.php'` **actually pointing to different databases**. While class itself is absolutely database independent.

Comment: So, **I have not a slightest idea,** why do you create duplicates

Comment: Right I got you point :) so i got this stuff already in place. I just confused myself :) Thank you Your Common Sense

Comment: If you solved your question please enter it as an answer and select it as the accepted answer. Otherwise delete it. We don't append "SOLVED" to the title here.

Comment: @Your Common Sense I found my problem and fixed it. As you can see in  product.class.php class i have added require_once "databass.class.php"; which was wrong. I shouldnt have used this in class but in the web page before initializing the class. Thank you for you advice ;)